# Example of a field extension of degree 2 which is not Galois

Tags: galois-theory

What is an example of a field extension of degree $2$ which is not Galois?
By definition, if $E/F$ is Galois, then $E$ is finite, separable, and normal over $F$. We know that every field extension of degree $2$ is normal, so we have to find a field extension that is inseparable.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure that there exists. It has to be normal, but it doesn't have to be separable.

Answer (score 1):

The most typical example of a non-separable extension is $\Bbb F_p(t^{1/p})/\Bbb F_p(t)$ for a prime $p$; this has degree $p$ so if you take $p=2$ you have your answer.

Comment: Why does it have degree $p$? The degree of the minimal polynomial is $p-1$, no?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $t^{1/p}$ is $x^p-t$. This is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ by Eisenstein's criterion.  Hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ by Gauss's lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Your example will need to be in characteristic $2$, otherwise quadratic extensions are always Galois.

If $K$ has characteristic $2$, then there are two kinds of quadratic extensions:

- $L=K(\sqrt{a})$, where $a\in K$ is not a square, is always inseparable;
- $L=K(\phi^{-1}(a))$ with $\phi(x)=x^2+x$, where $a\in K$ is not on the image of $\phi$, is always separable.

Note that of course the first case can never happen if all elements of $K$ are squares, ie if $K$ is perfect.

You can take any example of the first kind, such as the one given by Alex Mathers, which is the standard one.